# Consume ASP.NET WebApi from MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've started working on a new project where I'm exposing client functionality via WebApi so that I can reuse the same functionality across multiple devices, but there's some functionality that is shared between mobile devices and the hosting application.

My question is while I know how to consume the WebApi's from devices I'm drawing up a bit of a blank on the best way, best practice, or just something that works on how to consume the WebApi from within the MVC project that's hosting the api.

My first thought would be to just instantiate the controllers as needed the way I would any other class however I've got a sneaking suspicion that while it will work this is a bad approach.

The other thought would be to use the HttpClient. Although I've had any luck with it as I can never find the api's

```
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpServer(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));
client.PutAsJsonAsync("/api/project/login", Json(model));
```

Comment: Why does the application need to consume its own external facing API?  If the application needs functionality that the API exposes, can't it just call that functionality directly?  If you have a WebAPI method and a Controller method which need to do the same thing, that "same thing" should be abstracted into a function or object in shared code and both those methods would call it internally.

Comment: +1 to the above; even if they are two separate solutions you can just reference one from the other and directly consume the objects that comprise the WebAPI...

Comment: Answer for your second approach can be found below.
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: Well David, i agree with you, but i think it will depend on the project, business/infra requirements, in a distributed application it would be best to use the API to make the database and/or logic as a central "access point", its better then have different versions of a DLL in a lot of solutions in servers or devices like Smartphones, Tablets or Windows applications. In a distributed solution you can't handle it internally even if one of your apps resides in the same server, because of maintenance. I have one solution in this scenario. But again i agree with you, if the solution permits that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a subjective question since there really isn't a "right" answer. Essentially, you need to take multiple points into consideration.

- How safe is it to go the easy route and dependency resolve a controller instance?
- Will this logic be used in other places?
- Are these really two separate application concerns?

Essentially, if the API and the MVC application have difference concerns then they should be properly separated and the MVC application should call the WebAPI application using the HttpClient. This can reduce attack vectors and separate application concerns quite well.

If the MVC and WebAPI are both exposing the same information and security/separation of concerns isn't an issue then dependency resolving a controller should suffice.

If the logic isn't a separation of concerns issue and it will be used in multiple places then factoring it out into common components would likely be your best bet.

Shooting from the hip this sounds like a small application that could benefit from dependency resolving a controller in the immediate future. As the application grows (or if it is already planned to be large) then separating the logic into a proper SOA format would be beneficial.

tl;dr - SO really can't answer this question without knowing what the application is and will do. Be pragmatic.